# error in installing Xcode 3.2 on Snow Leopard

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-snow-leopard, xcode3.2

I have downloaded Xcode 3.2 with iOS SDK (4.1 GB) two times from Apple Developer's Website. When I try to install Xcode, it gives an error stating that "an unexpected error occurred. Please contact the manufacturer of software". It also gives error when I try to copy Xcode file to any USB Drive or any other computer via LAN. I have tried this at two different Mac computers both running Snow Leopard, but the problem is same.

I have wasted more than a week on that issue. Kindly let me know any solution. Urgent replies are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: why are u downloading the old version. Download latest 4.3.2 from 'APP STORE' so that u'll get updates of it when new version is released.

Comment: It sounds like there is a problem with the download.

Comment: I am downloading it from developer.apple.com ... Xcode 4.3.2 is for Lion but i have Snow Leopard and I am not willing to upgrade it to Lion. What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried contacting apple support then?

Comment: I have tried to access Apple Developer Forum but I am not registered in any iOS Developer Program. Can I still contact Apple Support?

Comment: XCode 4.2 works on Snow Leopard. Don't waste your time with 3.x - 4.x is much, much better.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem before.

If you go to the console, you should see a msg by xcode that is something along the lines that this version of Xcode could not be verified for install.

Don't ask why but if you turn back the clock of computer by about two years and try installing again, it should work perfectly.

Else, you would find a new lead looking at the console msg.